# Logstash INPUT MySQL

Tags: mysql, logging, elasticsearch, logstash

Can't find any input plugin for Relational Databases in Logstash Documentation.

What is the best approach to import data from one Relational Database Table with logstash? Is to connect Elastic Search directly to the database using JDBC?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to use JDBC River (https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc) for loading JDBC data into elastic search (or write your own code to do it).

It looks like there are several JIRAs open requesting JDBC loading in Logstash, but they haven't been worked: https://logstash.jira.com/browse/LOGSTASH-1764

Answer (score 3):

There's [this](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-jdbc)

> WIP: Under Development, NOT FOR PRODUCTION
>
> This is a plugin for Logstash.
>
> It is fully free and fully open source. The license is Apache 2.0, meaning you are pretty much free to use it however you want in whatever way.
>
> Logstash provides infrastructure to automatically generate documentation for this plugin. We use the asciidoc format to write documentation so any comments in the source code will be first converted into asciidoc and then into html. All plugin documentation are placed under one central location.

Comment: using the logstash jdbc input plugin is the way to go nowadays, since the elastic rivers are deprecated now

Answer (score 2):

So far, there is no any Logstash API for reading SQL.

For my recommendation, you can write a program/script such as JAVA/python to read the logs  from sql database and write to a file. Then use logstash [file](http://logstash.net/docs/latest/inputs/file)
API to read from the file. The Logstash website has getting started tutorial. It is easy to learn.
Good Luck

Comment: Ben its ok that way! that way there is no advantage using logstash for that. Maybe the actual best approach for this need is to integrate elastic search directly with the database.