# Logstash input as Database

Tags: logstash, log-shipping

As logstash is a very good shipper tool for real time data from log file,tcp,upd. Like that, i have a requirement to track database insertions values in real time. Mean, if some record  are added in DB, it should reflect immeditely to Logstash. How to make it possible without changing anything in DB side(like triggers)?

Comment: You can refer to this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23493282/logstash-input-mysql

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ben. I am woundering if there is any other shipper rather than LogStash which has this feature?